# Why is there so much overhead when using https instead of http with aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, aiohttp

I am transforming a stript from sync `requests` to the async `aiohttp`, because I would like to make really fast requests to multiple servers. One thing I am struggling with now is that the response time of HTTPS is much higher with 
`aiohttp` than with `requests`.

Below is a code example that is as short as possible where I make a request to HTTP or HTTPS and for the `requests` library this doesn't make that big of a difference, but with `aiohttp` it does. The two used methods to make the request are:

`requests.request('GET', url)` and
`aiohttp.request('GET', url)`

So what I don't understand is: Why is `aiohttp` so much worse in handling https requests?

```
import time
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import requests

URL = 'https://google.com' # 'https://google.com' #  takes asyncio ~x2 as long

time1 = time.time()
responseAsync = []
async def fetch(session):
    async with session.request(method='GET', url=URL) as response:
        return await response.read()

async def run():
    uris = ['list of uris, not used now']
    tasks = []

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for uri in uris:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(session))
            tasks.append(task)
        responseAsync.append(await asyncio.gather(*tasks))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run())
loop.run_until_complete(future)

time2 = time.time()

session = requests.Session()
responseSync = [session.request('GET', URL)]  # and some extra more requests..

time3 = time.time()


totaltimeAsyncio = (time2 - time1) * 1000
totaltimeRequests = (time3 - time2) * 1000
print('Response time async request:', totaltimeAsyncio)
print('Response time sync request:', totaltimeRequests)
```

output HTTP:

```
Response time async request: 130.8588981628418
Response time sync request: 107.31077194213867
```

output HTTPS:

```
Response time async request: 571.195125579834
Response time sync request: 167.56391525268555
```

Comment: I don't see the same strange behaviour. I have HTTP: async = 98.5, sync = 99.5 and HTTPS: async = 141.5, sync = 137.6. (Python 3.8, aiohttp 3.6.2 on osx).

Comment: Thanks for checking! I still don't know what the problem was, but after creating a new project with a updated virtual environment the problem doesn't exist anymore :) But still, anying that I don't know what the real problem is..

Comment: Have you checked your aiohttp versions? Maybe a bug existed in some version?

Comment: aiohttp is up to date, howerver I was running python 3.6.3 and updated it to 3.8 and that did fix it.